# Determine continuity at $(0,0)$ of the function $\frac{e^{xy}-1}{|x|+|y|}$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, continuity

Prepping for a calculus exam. In a past exam I saw the following question:

> Determine whether the following function is continuous at $(0,0)$:
>   $$
> f(x,y)=
> \begin{cases}
> \frac{e^{xy}-1}{|x|+|y|}, & \text{if $(x,y)\neq$(0,0)} \\ 
> 0 & \text{if $(x,y)=$(0,0)}
> \end{cases}
> \
> $$

Not sure where to begin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I will show that $g(x,y)=\frac{xy}{|x|+|y|}$ is continuous at the origin (putting $g(0,0)=0$, of course).  If we write it in polar coordinates $x=r\cos\theta,y=r\sin\theta$, we get:
   $$
   g(r,\theta)=\frac{r\cos\theta\sin\theta}{|\cos\theta|+|\sin\theta|}.
   $$
   Note that the denominator is nonzero, i.e. $|\cos\theta|+|\sin\theta|\ge C$ for some $C>0$ (exercise).  Therefore,
   $$
   |g-0|\le \frac{r|\cos\theta\sin\theta|}{C}\le \frac{r}{2C}=\frac{1}{2C}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}.
   $$
   We can then use the $\epsilon/\delta$ definition of continuity (exercise).
2. Here's two approaches you can try for $f(x,y)$:

a. $e^{xy}=1+xy+\frac{(xy)^2}{2!}+\dots$ (Taylor Series).

b. $e^{xy}-1=xy\int_0^1e^{(xy)s}ds$ (FTC).

Answer (score 1):

In 2D you can approach the origin from more directions than just from the left or right in 1D.

You need to show that any such approach gives a limit value which is the same as the function value. Or find a counter example.

Comment: I know. Trying to find a counterexample I tried (0,t),(t,0),(t,t),(t,log(t)), all to no avail. Also wasn’t able to show an upper or lower bound which converges or diverges

Comment: If you decide to go that road, the usual methods are: attempting an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof of the limit, checking if the problem simplifies for a different symmetry (e.g. polar coordinates) or apply a helper theorem, like the squeeze / sandwich theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

For $y \neq 0$

$$|\frac{e^{xy}-1}{|x|+|y|} | \leq |\frac{e^{xy}-1}{|y|}|=| \frac{e^{xy}-1}{y}|$$

Since for positive numbers $a$ and $b$, a smaller denominator $b$ of $\frac{a}{b}$ means a larger result, keeping $a$ fixed but allowing $b$ to vary.

> $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{e^{xy}-1}{y}=\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}  x \frac{e^{xy}-1}{xy}=(0)(1)=0$$ By squeeze theorem the limit must be zero (work out $y=0$, $x \neq 0$ separately and also $y \neq 0$, $x=0$).

Comment: then can I use L'Hopital as y->0?

Comment: Not sure if you can use lhopitals for 2 variables.  Just note for instance that $\frac{e^{3y}-1}{y}=3 \frac{e^{3y}-1}{3y}  \to 3$. In a similar spirit we can do a similar trick here.

Comment: but in this case in the denominator I have absolute value of y and in the numerator I don't. so it's not the same value

Comment: If added a spoiler where you can view my intended solution @ikoikoia